# Prevent converting spaces to non-breaking spaces in nowrap textarea

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

In Chrome and Safari, having a `<textarea>` with `white-space:nowrap` applied causes various space characters at the end of the input to be converted to non-breaking spaces (ASCII 160, Hex `\xA0`).

#### Demo of Problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ND2LS/2/

```html
<textarea rows="2" cols="40">foo</textarea>
<label>ASCII: <output></output></label>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var t = document.querySelector('textarea'),
      o = document.querySelector('output');
  (t.onchange = t.oninput = function(){
    var s = t.value;
    for (var cc=[],i=s.length;i--;) cc[i]=s.charCodeAt(i);
    o.value = cc.join(", ");
})();
</script>
```

Typing spaces at the end of that will show the following output with each press:

```
ASCII: 102, 111, 111, 160
ASCII: 102, 111, 111, 32, 160
ASCII: 102, 111, 111, 32, 160, 160
ASCII: 102, 111, 111, 32, 160, 32, 160
```

How can I prevent this behavior of corrupting user input, while still preventing line wrapping?

<sub>*Experienced on Safari v7.0.1 OS X and Chrome v33.0.1750.117 OS X. Firefox does not experience the problem.*</sub>

Comment: If you didn't have nearly 100k rep, I'd say this smelled like a rep / badge grab...

Comment: @cale_b :) No, truly my intention is to help others. I ran into this baffling behavior and while writing up the question happened to find a solution from suggested-similar question.

Comment: I know - thanks for sharing the knowledge! Anyone else did that (answer / question within 1 minute of each other) and I'd cry foul.  Was just poking some fun... ;)

Comment: @cale_b even if it was a rep badge, answering your only question is totally allowed. if it was a basic one, it'd be downvoted and removed

Answer (score 2):

The so-called DOM0 `wrap="off"` attribute for textarea avoids this problem, and still prevents line-wrapping.

#### Fixed Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ND2LS/3/

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="40" wrap="off">foo</textarea>
```